# ChartJS options.scales is being completely ignored

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to make a chart which has years along the x-axis and dollar amounts along the y-axis. I finally got close to what I'm looking for, but I found that because the x coordinates are numbers, ChartJS is putting commas in them which looks really strange for years.

After some digging, I used the callbacks. `options.plugin.tooltip.callbacks.label` worked to let me remove commas in the tooltips, but when I use `options.scales.x[0].ticks.callback` to try to fix the labels on the bottom, not only does it not work, but I don't see the `console.log` statement in their ever being printed so it seems it's not even calling the callback. I've tried several variations of how to do the callback based on what I found online and on Stack Overflow which I think correspond to the different ways ChartJS did this in different versions. (I'm on version 3.5.1.)

Then, I realized that... none of the options under `options.scales` appear to have any effect. I change the min, the title, the tick settings (color to red, callback, etc.) and it has no effect. (This also explains why I was having trouble when using the line chart and had to switch to scatter; apparently `type: 'linear'` wasn't being picked up nor did it do anything different when I set it to `type: 'date'` or whatever the exact working was for that.)

Meanwhile, the other options like `options.showLine` or `options.elements` do have an effect and I'm seeing the chart and not getting any errors in the console. So, it is picking up the options, just ignoring everything I have in `options.scales`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    // Sample data added to make this example self-contained
    // This is my internal data format
    let data = {
        "Series1": [ {x: 2001, y: 100 },  {x: 2002, y: 110 },  {x: 2003, y: 107 }, ],
        "Series2": [ {x: 2001, y: 107 },  {x: 2002, y: 102 },  {x: 2004, y: 95 }, ],
    }

    // Define data //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // I convert data to format ChartJS wants and add a few options
    let datasets = [];
    for(let label in data) {
        let c = colorIterator.next().value
        datasets.push({
            label: label,
            data: data[label],
            backgroundColor: c,
            borderColor: c,
        });
    }

    // Define options //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let chartConfig = {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: { datasets: datasets, },
        options: {
            title: { display: false },
            indexAxis: 'x', responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false,
            showLine: true,
            elements: {
                line: { display: true, tension: 0, borderWidth: 1, fill: false, },
                point: { radius: 3 }
            },
            interaction: { mode: 'x', },
            scales: {
                x: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    min: 1995, max: (new Date()).getFullYear()+1, stepSize: 1,
                    title: { display: true, text: 'Year' },
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                        major: { enabled: true },
                        color: 'red',
                        callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                            console.log(value);
                            return Chart.Ticks.formatters.numeric.apply(this, [value, index, ticks])
                                .replace(",","");
                        }
                    }
                }], 
                y: [{
                    title: { display: true, text: '$' },
                    ticks: {
                        display: true,
                        color: 'red',
                    },
                }],
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(context) {
                            let label = context.dataset.label || '';
                            if(label) {
                                let x = context.label.replace(",","");
                                let y = context.formattedValue;
                                return 'Year ' + x + ' "' + label + '": $' + y;
                            } else { return 'x'; }
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    };

    // MAKE CHART //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    let mainChart = new Chart(document.getElementById(c.id), chartConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/axes/cartesian/category.html) the scales are not arrays. All the scales are objects in the scale object.

So you will need to change your code to this:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      // x options
    },
    y: {
      // y options
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I've seen some examples on Stack Overflow that had them as arrays (must be from the V2 days). So, I think when fixing another issue I must have changed my code based on one of those examples and thought they were an actual fix when, in reality, they just worked by coincidence because the ignored scales led to the defaults being used.